# Sending ZeroMQ messages from openvswitch to SDN controller

Tags: zeromq, openflow, openvswitch

I have been working with two C programs for the past few months, one is a **ZeroMQ** publisher and the other a **ZeroMQ** subscriber.
They exchange simple string messages between Virtual Machines and everything works fine.

Now, in one of the VMs I've been working on (VM A) I configured an **openvswitch** and in another VM a **Ryu controller**. The diagram is the following:

[image]

I "bounded" the bridge interface of OVS to the eth3 interface of VM A. Everything works well and flow-entries are added by the Ryu controller or manually added by me.

**Now**, I want to add the ZeroMQ publisher-subscriber programs I had already used countless times. Here, the controller is the subscriber and OVS the publisher.

However, the messages never arrive to the controller... If I run the ZeroMQ publisher from another machine on `net A` that does **NOT** have OVS installed and configured, messages arrive to the Ryu controller successfully.

When I run the publisher and subscriber, this is the output of `netstat -at` on both machines. VM A is "OpenWrt" and the Ryu controller is "control" (consider only the last line in @control VM):

[image]

[image]

Is there something I'm missing? Is it really impossible to send TCP messages from de OVS to the controller? Should I create some kind of tunnel from VM A to the controller where messages would flow through? Or is it just an issue with ZeroMQ that does not work with Openflow enabled architectures?

If any of you ever worked with a message queueing technology in Openflow environments, please let me know.

I appreciate any kind of help, I've been stuck for weeks.

Note: I can ping VM A from controller and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : *Is there something I'm missing?*

Given no MCVE-code was provided, there is missing a pair of LoS-visibility test results, from:

```
<ZMQ_SUB_HOST>:~$ traceroute --sport=<ZMQ_TRANSPORT_PORT#> <ZMQ_PUB_HOST>
```

and

```
<ZMQ_PUB_HOST>:~$ traceroute --sport=<ZMQ_TRANSPORT_PORT#> <ZMQ_SUB_HOST>
```

> *Note: I can ping VM A from controller and vice-versa.*

This remark sounds promising, yet both the LoS-visibility test results and the MCVE-code details are important, but missing.

> **Q** : *Should I create some kind of tunnel from VM A to the controller where messages would flow through?*

Sure, you definitely can. This will isolate L3-level issues and your tunneling-path will provide a way to ignore all these, at a cost of some slight latency trade-off.

> **Q** : *Or is it just an issue with ZeroMQ that does not work with Openflow enabled architectures?*

There is no specific reason for blaming ZeroMQ infrastructure to stop working but due to an L3/SDN-related yet unspecified so far issue. Given a fair **`tcp://`**-transport-class path exists and is used in a properly configured ZeroMQ transport-infrastructure consisting of ad-hoc, dynamic setup of
**M**-`.bind( <class>://<addr>:<port> )`-s **: N**-`.connect( <class>://<addr>:<port> )`-s relation, reporting no error-state(s) on respective operation(s), the ZeroMQ shall and will work as it always does.